# Using funct() and aggregate() in r and its choosing wrong data set

Tags: r

Gross Loss is a column in DatasetOne but also is a column in DatasetTwo, Three, etc
Age is a column in DatasetOne, but also is a column in DatasetTwo, Three, etc

This is the function I used

```
ag <- function (x,y,z,d)
{
 aggregate(x ~ y, FUN=z, data=d)
}
```

once i make this function, i do

```
sample <- ag(GrossLoss, Age, mean, DatasetOne)
```

It says  "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'GrossLoss' not found" 
which is fixed if i use attach(DatasetOne)

So i changed the function to

```
ag <- function (x,y,z,d)
{
 attach(d)
 aggregate(x ~ y, FUN=z, data=d)
 detach(d)
}
```

But instead of creating a data, it creates a value/environement

How do i solve this? It seems like it is the "data=" bit that is not functioning correctly the same thing happens when i try to make a function for 
    plot (.., data=d) 
as well.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use `paste` and the `formula`

```
ag <- function (x,y,z,d){
  aggregate(as.formula(paste(x, y, sep="~")), data=d, FUN = z)
}
```

and then call the function

```
ag('GrossLoss', 'Age', mean, DatasetOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this. `match.call` would evaluate all the arguments inside the function. Then you can eval to use the data frame, d.

```
ag <- function (x,y,z,d)
{
    arguments <- as.list(match.call())
    x = eval(arguments$x, d)
    y = eval(arguments$y, d)
    aggregate(x ~ y, FUN = z, d)       
}
```

Then Call would be:

```
ag(x, y, mean, d)
```